# Need to shorten my JQuery UI JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a project where it's an accordion with thumbnails inside and when you click on one a picture shows up next to the accordion. So far I've managed to get it to work using the following code:

HTML:

```
<!--thumbs--->
<a id="1a" href="#"><img src="../../images/thumb/1000.jpg" /></a>
<a id="2a" href="#"><img src="../../images/thumb/1001.jpg" /></a>
<a id="3a" href="#"><img src="../../images/thumb/1002.jpg" /></a>
<a id="4a" href="#"><img src="../../images/thumb/1003.jpg" /></a>
<a id="5a" href="#"><img src="../../images/thumb/1004.jpg" /></a>
<a id="6a" href="#"><img src="../../images/thumb/1005.jpg" /></a>
<!--large photos--->
<img class="hide1" id="1b" src="../../images/fullsize/1000.jpg" />
<img class="hide1" id="2b" src="../../images/fullsize/1001.jpg" />
<img class="hide1" id="3b" src="../../images/fullsize/1002.jpg" />
<img class="hide1" id="4b" src="../../images/fullsize/1003.jpg" />
<img class="hide1" id="5b" src="../../images/fullsize/1004.jpg" />
<img class="hide1" id="6b" src="../../images/fullsize/1005.jpg" />
```

CSS:

```
.hide1{
   display:none;
}
.show{
   display:block !important;
}
```

and the JS (under jquery UI):

```
$(function() {
$( "#1a" ).click(function() {
        $( ".show" ).toggleClass( "show", 0 );
        return false;
});
$( "#1a" ).click(function() {
    $( "#1b" ).toggleClass( "show", 0 );
    return false;
});


$( "#2a" ).click(function() {
    $( ".show" ).toggleClass( "show", 0 );
    return false;
});
$( "#2a" ).click(function() {
    $( "#2b" ).toggleClass( "show", 0 );
    return false;
});


$( "#3a" ).click(function() {
    $( ".show" ).toggleClass( "show", 0 );
    return false;
});
$( "#3a" ).click(function() {
    $( "#3b" ).toggleClass( "show", 0 );
    return false;
});


$( "#4a" ).click(function() {
    $( ".show" ).toggleClass( "show", 0 );
    return false;
});
$( "#4a" ).click(function() {
    $( "#4b" ).toggleClass( "show", 0 );
    return false;
});


$( "#5a" ).click(function() {
    $( ".show" ).toggleClass( "show", 0 );
    return false;
});
$( "#5a" ).click(function() {
    $( "#5b" ).toggleClass( "show", 0 );
    return false;
});
});
```

Does anyone know a way I can shorten the JS? I have over 100 pics and don't particularly want to do that for all of them unless i have to.

Comment: Better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ IMO.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Give the links a class:

```
<a id="1a" href="#" class="ThumbClick">
```

Then apply click with class and use of this:

```
$('.ThumbClick').click(function(){
    var $id = this.id.replace('a','b');

    $('.show,#'+$id).toggleClass('show',0);
    return false;
});
```

Since you're toggling the same class you show be able to consolidate it into a comma-separated selector. Use of the class and `this.id` makes the function universal, but specific to link clicked.

[Here is a working jsFiddle based on this logic](http://jsfiddle.net/3XVCj/).

The pictures haven't been uploaded obviously, but in Chrome developer tools you can see the classes change for the pictures appropriately. If you wanted to continue the bubbling but prevent the link action:

```
$('.ThumbClick').click(function(e){
    var $id = this.id.replace('a','b');

    e.preventDefault();
    $('.show,#'+$id).toggleClass('show',0);
});
```

Just offering it as an alternative, either should work fine. [Here is the jsFiddle for that logic](http://jsfiddle.net/3XVCj/1/).

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks so much

Comment: dont thank me, thank the checkmark ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should be good enough

```
$(function () {
    $("#1a , #2a, #3a, #4a, #5a").on('click', function () {
        var newId = this.id.replace('a', 'b');

        $('#' + newId).toggleClass("show", 0);
        $(".show").toggleClass("show", 0);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Use `this.id` which is the id of the current element that is clicked.

Replace it with b and toggleClass for that..